# How to add custom Aggregation functions for GroupBy in Dask ? for example average, mode, median, 95th percentile etc

Tags: dask, dask-dataframe

I am not able to understand what will be *chunk, agg and finalize* in following code.

```
mode = dd.Aggregation('mode', chunk, agg, finalize)
```

Also, types and implementation way of same.
Can someone guide/help me on same **in Dask** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments `chunk`, `agg`, and `finalize` are described with examples in the docstring for `dask.dataframe.Aggregation`, which is available online here: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.groupby.Aggregation

If you have particular questions that you would like clarified about that explanation then I encourage you to mention them specifically.

Comment: Yes that I understood. But now I am unable to develop/understand logic for calculating 95th percentile, median, distinct varience, mode aggregation for grouped data.

Comment: if you have any, can you please guide me some code snippets for same ? @MRocklin

Comment: I recommend doing web searches for parallel versions of those algorithms.  What you're asking for is not trivial.